# HTTP 405 Not Allowed - Spring Boot + Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a simple rest API which works with database. It worked properly until I added the security part. Now it gives HTTP 405 Not Allowed on the POST and DELETE requests. I have no idea why. The GET requests work properly.

So here is the controller class:

```
@Controller
public class MarkerController {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MarkerController.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    private MarkerServiceInterface markerService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/markers", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<Marker> getMarkers(@RequestParam(value="city", defaultValue="") String city) {
        logger.info("HANDLE GET REQUEST");



        return this.markerService.getAllMarkers();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/markers/new", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Marker addMarker(@RequestBody Marker marker) {
        logger.info("HANDLE POST REQUEST");

        this.markerService.addMarker(marker);
        return marker;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/markers/delete", method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public @ResponseBody String deleteMarker(@RequestParam(value="id", defaultValue="") String id) {
        logger.info("HANDLE DELETE REQUEST");
        if (!id.equals("")) {
            logger.info(id);
            this.markerService.deleteMarker(Long.parseLong(id));
        }
        return "";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/admin/map")
    public String trafficSpy() {
        logger.info("HANDLE MAP");
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/admin")
    public String admin() {
        return "admin";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/login")
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }

}
```

This is the SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsService")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(
                passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http    
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**")
            .access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
            .antMatchers("/markers/**")
            .access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .failureUrl("/login?error")
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/403");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return encoder;
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }
}
```

The DELETE request is called with the following ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "localhost:8080/markers/delete?id=" + currentMarker.get("id"),
        type: 'DELETE',
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
```

And here is the message given in the console:

```
2015-05-11 15:48:13.671  WARN 8279 --- [nio-8181-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'DELETE' not supported
```

These are the headers of the response. I can see that in AlLLOW I have only GET and HEAD. So if I'm right, this means that the method in the controller accepts only GET and HEAD requests.

```
(Status-Line)               HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Server                      Apache-Coyote/1.1
x-content-type-options      nosniff
x-xss-protection            1; mode=block
Cache-Control               no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma                      no-cache
Expires                     0
X-Frame-Options             DENY
Allow                       GET, HEAD
Content-Type                application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding           chunked
Date                        Mon, 11 May 2015 17:35:31 GMT
```

In the response I have this exeption:

```
org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
```

Any idea what is causing this problem? How can I allow the POST and DELETE methods?

Comment: How are you calling delete, can you paste the code for that, and you dont need to give default value to "", you can just check it. I would suggest to remove RequestMethod.Delete parameter itself.

Comment: Why didnt you remove the RequestMethod.delete and the default value? Also, at your function(result), you should redirect.   Please dont return "", if you want to return nothing,just declare return type as void. Why dont you try using a simple controller method and calling it from JSP/HTMl directly rather then messing around with AJAX.

Comment: Removing the request parameter didn't fix anything. Neither did removing the RequestMethod.DELETE.
I don't think the problem is there since the code worked fine before adding the security.

My client is not only a jsp page but an Android client too.

Comment: For clarification: If you remove http security the `POST` and `DELETE` succeed?

Comment: i think you missing the `csrf` token. Please can you check if the error messages say something about that.

Comment: What do you mean by an Android client. Are you accessing the code via REST through an android app?

Comment: @ManuZi, yes, the problem was with the csrf token. You can add it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forget the `csrf`-Token.

It's recommended that you add the csrf-Token in the meta-tag. You can read it in the [Spring Security Documentation](http://spring.io/blog/2013/08/21/spring-security-3-2-0-rc1-highlights-csrf-protection/)

With this you can do the following:

```
$(function () {
  var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
  var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
  $(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to leave an additional solution, because although Manu Zi's answer is a correct one, it wasn't immediately clear to me *why* the first time I came across this issue and found this answer.

The underlying issue was obscured by the immediate problem of the 405 Method Not Allowed.

In my case, there were two factors at play. Firstly, there was no POST method for my AccessDenied controller, which resulted in a 405 when a POST method was denied and redirected to the AccessDenied controller. This was only evident after turning up debug logging on `org.springframework.web`.

Once that was clear, it was a matter of figuring out why I was getting access denied. All the permissions and roles were correct, but having upgraded from Spring 3 to 4, I found that CSRF protection was enabled by default. It either needs to be disabled, or you have to use Manu Zi's solution.

To disable it, see:
[spring security 4 csrf disable via xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31312844/spring-security-4-csrf-disable-via-xml)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the protocol had to be `https` instead of `http`