# spring security 4 csrf disable via xml

Tags: xml, spring-security

Is there a way to disable CSRF token in spring security via XML configuration?
I see only java configuration online..can xml based examples. Using spring framework 4.0

Answer (score 44):

> As of Spring Security 4.0, CSRF protection is enabled by default with
>   XML configuration. If you would like to disable CSRF protection, the
>   corresponding XML configuration can be seen below.
>
> ```
> <http>
>   <!-- ... -->
>   <csrf disabled="true"/>
> </http>
> ```
>
> CSRF protection is enabled by default with Java configuration. If you
>   would like to disable CSRF, the corresponding Java configuration can
>   be seen below. Refer to the Javadoc of csrf() for additional
>   customizations in how CSRF protection is configured.
>
> ```
> @EnableWebSecurity
> public class WebSecurityConfig extends
> WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
>
> @Override
> protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
>   http
>   .csrf().disable();
> }
> }
> ```

See below link
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-configure

Comment: In which xml i need to add `<http></http>` to disable the csrf token

Comment: Just adding ``<csrf disabled="true"/>`` works for spring security 5

Comment: omg, this just saved me!  I have been working on this issue for weeks and just found this and it worked in spring security 5.  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 14):

In your context.xml, assuming you have the xsd declaration for security:

```
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security",
```

Inside the `<security:http>` element add

```
<security:csrf disabled="true"/>
```

Comment: the to the point answer with minimum possible words. Saved my day  +1

Answer (score 6):

For total beginners, if you are following Spring MVC beginners guide book then in `security-context.xml` file add `csrf disabled="true"` line:

```
  <security:http auto-config="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/products/add"
      access="ROLE_ADMIN" />

    <security:form-login login-page="/login"
      default-target-url="/products/add" 
      authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />

    <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />

    <security:csrf disabled="true" />
  </security:http>
```