# Spring security oauth2 resource server failing to call authorization server

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

I am trying to set up a oauth2 environment with client , resource and auth server running at 3 different places. Login happens fine. But when I try to access any resource via the client server I am getting error. I have defined the error at the bottom.

Following is my resource server code

**Resource server code**

**OAuth2ResourceConfig**

```
package com.rivigo.oauth2.resource.config;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.BearerTokenExtractor;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.TokenExtractor;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.AccessTokenConverter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultAccessTokenConverter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.RemoteTokenServices;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;


@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class OAuth2ResourceConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private TokenExtractor tokenExtractor = new BearerTokenExtractor();

    @Bean
    public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer properties(){
      PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
      ClassPathResource[] resources = new ClassPathResource[ ]
        { new ClassPathResource( "application.properties" ) };
      ppc.setLocations( resources );
      ppc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders( true );
      return ppc;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .addFilterAfter(new OncePerRequestFilter() {
                @Override
                protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                        HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                        throws ServletException, IOException {
                    // We don't want to allow access to a resource with no token so clear
                    // the security context in case it is actually an OAuth2Authentication
                    if (tokenExtractor.extract(request) == null) {
                        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
                    }
                    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
                }
            }, AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class);

        http
             .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
            .antMatcher("/user");
    }

    @Bean
    public AccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        return new DefaultAccessTokenConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public RemoteTokenServices remoteTokenServices(final @Value("${auth.server.url:http://localhost:8080/rivigo-auth/oauth/check_token/}") String checkTokenUrl,
            final @Value("${auth.server.clientId:pilot-client}") String clientId,
            final @Value("${auth.server.clientsecret:pilot}") String clientSecret) {

        final RemoteTokenServices remoteTokenServices = new RemoteTokenServices();
        remoteTokenServices.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl(checkTokenUrl);
        remoteTokenServices.setClientId(clientId);
        remoteTokenServices.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
        remoteTokenServices.setAccessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter());
        return remoteTokenServices;
    }
}
```

**SecurityConfig**

```
package com.rivigo.oauth2.resource.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }
}
```

**MethodSecurityConfig**

```
package com.rivigo.oauth2.resource.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.MethodSecurityExpressionHandler;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.expression.OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler;

@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        return new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    }
}
```

**ResourceServerWebConfig**

```
package com.rivigo.oauth2.resource.config;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.rivigo.oauth2.resource.controller" })
public class ResourceServerWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(converter());
    }

    @Bean
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter() {
        return new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    }

}
```

**And following is my Auth server config**

**Oauth2Config**

```
package com.rivigo.oauth2.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultAccessTokenConverter;

@EnableAuthorizationServer
@Configuration
public class Oauth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(final ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients)
            throws Exception {
        clients
            .inMemory()
                .withClient("pilot-client")
                .secret("pilot")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "refresh_token")
                .scopes(new String[] { "read", "write" });
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer)
            throws Exception {
        oauthServer
            .allowFormAuthenticationForClients()
            .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
            .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultAccessTokenConverter defaultAccessTokenConverter() {
        return new DefaultAccessTokenConverter();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
            throws Exception {
        endpoints
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .accessTokenConverter(defaultAccessTokenConverter());
    }
}
```

So I am using remote token services for verifying the token. My request to the resource server is not getting served. After debugging I found that the check_token endpoint is returning 403 forbidden. I am using the following client server code.
https://github.com/sharmaritesh/spring-angularjs-oauth2-sample/tree/master/sonc-ng-ui

I don't see any error logs in the resource server or the auth server. The client server gives me the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 Internal Server Error
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:94)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.http.OAuth2ErrorHandler.handleError(OAuth2ErrorHandler.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:614)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:570)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.doExecute(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:128)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:530)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForEntity(RestTemplate.java:262)
    at org.springframework.cloud.security.oauth2.resource.UserInfoTokenServices.getMap(UserInfoTokenServices.java:105)
    at org.springframework.cloud.security.oauth2.resource.UserInfoTokenServices.loadAuthentication(UserInfoTokenServices.java:58)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:211)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at rites.sample.ng.SoncWebapp$SecurityConfiguration$1.doFilterInternal(SoncWebapp.java:82)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientContextFilter.doFilter(OAuth2ClientContextFilter.java:60)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricFilterAutoConfiguration$MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**UPDATE**

Proramatically, when the spring enabled resource server tries to make a call to the check token end point (oauth/check_token) I am getting 403 forbidden error. Whereas when I do the same call via postman I am getting success.

**Post man call details::**
http://ip:port/rivigo-auth/oauth/check_token?token=6cdf8cb7-755f-4ddc-9ded-8bd1f9d4d386

Authorization  - Basic cGlsb3QtY2xpZW50OnBpbG90

Content-Type   - application/x-www-form-urlencoded

*Note. The headers and parameters added to the post man are fetched by putting a debug pointer in the resource server and coping the relevant details. So though the resource server has the correct data, Seems like spring is not passing the parameters in proper format.*

Comment: I was getting a 403 similar to you and my issue is because CSRF protection is enabled by default with Spring Security 4. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31312844/spring-security-4-csrf-disable-via-xml

Comment: Got that. I had to disable the CSRF filter. Can you post an answer so that I can accept it.