# HTTP 405 with embedded VAADIN UI in a SPRING-BOOT JSP based webapp

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, vaadin

I have integrated Vaadin 7 embedding the UI, as explained in Vaadin Book, in some JSP pages of a Spring Boot based application.

Despite the UI named "v-my-vaadin-ui" is correctly displayed when I call the path in which it is embedded (through a spring MVC controller) I got an HTTP 405 error when interacting with the UI.

Error is on the URL:

> http://localhost:8080/v-my-vaadin-ui/UIDL/?v-uiId=4

It seems that because in Spring Boot all controllers have only GET method allowed by default (POST has to be explicitly allowed as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30171265/http-405-not-allowed-spring-boot-spring-security))

Already tried disabling the CSRF and configuring Vaadin ralated paths in my Spring Security Configuration:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers("/vaadinServlet/**", 
"/UIDL/**", 
"/v-my-vaadin-ui/UIDL/**", 
"/v-my-vaadin-ui/PUSH/**", 
"/HEARTBEAT/**", "/VAADIN/**").permitAll();
http.csrf().disable();
```

because VAADIN integration is requiring no CSRF managed by Spring but this doesn't solve the problem.

The VAADIN application is very basic:

```
@SpringUI(path = "v-my-vaadin-ui")
public class MyVaadinUI extends UI {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8129815147461786549L;

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {

        final TextField name = new TextField("Name");
        final Button greetButton = new Button("Greet");

        greetButton.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                Notification.show("Hi " + name.getValue(), 
                                  Notification.Type.HUMANIZED_MESSAGE);
            }
        });

        VerticalLayout vl = new VerticalLayout(name, greetButton);
        vl.setSpacing(true);
        setContent(vl);
    }

}
```

But clicking on the Vaadin button the response code is 405 and the exception in detail is:

> .w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/], class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@4a8756c3]]]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported

Unfortunately I didn't find **any way to configure the POST method** for the UI as for a simple controller i.e. via

```
@RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
```

because this annotation cannot be used for Vaadin UI.

Moreover if I call **directly** the UI (i.e. not passing through a Spring controller) with the URL:

> http://localhost:8080/v-my-vaadin-ui

UI displays and works perfectly.

Any idea what is causing this problem? How can I allow the POST method?

Comment: could you please elaborate on the URL structure you are using to embed the UI? or a link to the tutorial you are following? if your direct UI works, then one explanation for embedding failing would be a mix up with relative links. the call to UI itself does basically nothing else but to return html where the UI is embedded "fullscreen".

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with this add-on? https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/jsp-integration

Comment: Hi Alejandro, thanks for the response, honestly I was not aware of your plugin (I've just created a custom tag that is using the JS described in the VAADIN documentation to embed an UI). I'm trying to add it to my maven pom.xml but getting the following exception:

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vaadin.server.ServiceDestroyListener
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
 [...]

It is compatible with: vaadin-spring-boot-starter-1.0.0 ?

Comment: Yes it suports it. You might be missing the Vaadin bom configuration in your pom.xml: https://github.com/alejandro-du/springboot-servlet-rest-vaadin-demo/blob/master/pom.xml#L44-L54

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!!

The problem was caused by an error I made in the JS script I was using to embed the VAADIN app (I've followed the documentation here: https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-embedding.html) in particular the code fragment for "serviceUrl" parameter:

```
"serviceUrl": "helloworld/",
```

that I've understood to be set with the **name of the application**, in my case "v-my-vaadin-ui".

But the correct "serviceUrl" in my case, is **still the default** one "vaadinServlet/" so changing from:

```
"serviceUrl": "v-my-vaadin-ui/",
```

to

```
"serviceUrl": "vaadinServlet/",
```

everything works.

Here below the complete code of the JSP tag to embed the vaadin app that works for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@tag description="ajax widget tag" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@attribute name="v_app_url"%>

<%-- Javascript as described here: https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-embedding.html --%>

<div>

    <div id="${v_app_url}" class="v-app myvaadinui" >
       <div class="v-app-loading"></div>
       <noscript>
        You have to enable javascript in your browser to use an application built with Vaadin.
       </noscript>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
        if (!window.vaadin)
            alert("Failed to load the bootstrap JavaScript: vaadinBootstrap.js");

            /* The UI Configuration */
            vaadin.initApplication("${v_app_url}", {
                "browserDetailsUrl": "${v_app_url}/",
                "serviceUrl": "vaadinServlet/",
                "widgetset": "com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet",
                "theme": "valo",
                "versionInfo": {"vaadinVersion": "7.4.4"},
                "vaadinDir": "/VAADIN/",
                "heartbeatInterval": 300,
                "debug": false,
                "standalone": false,
                "authErrMsg": {
                    "message": "Take note of any unsaved data, "+
                               "and <u>click here<\/u> to continue.",
                    "caption": "Authentication problem"
                },
                "comErrMsg": {
                    "message": "Take note of any unsaved data, "+
                               "and <u>click here<\/u> to continue.",
                    "caption": "Communication problem"
                },
                "sessExpMsg": {
                    "message": "Take note of any unsaved data, "+
                               "and <u>click here<\/u> to continue.",
                    "caption": "Session Expired"
                }
            });//]] >
     </script>

</div>
```